Find the thickness of a cubic shell?
So I’m trying to figure out the thickness of each layer of a layered cube.
So I’d be interested in really a general form if there is one, so I can test out different numbers to see which fits my needs the best, but here’s the question.
I have 3 layers of a cube, the inner most layer has a fixed side length and volume.
The middle layer has a fixed volume of the cubic shell, so assume we would have a specific mass of the material, and this material has a fixed density knowing the density, so the volume is fixed, and I want to find the thickness of the middle layer when it is melted/molded evenly directly over each face of the innermost layer with no gaps.
And the outer layer which again is a cubic shell, and can have variable volume, and fixed thickness on each face, which we want to figure out how much material is needed when putting a layer of a specified thickness over the now fixed two layer cube.
Does the following math look right?
So assume inner layer has side length s with a volume of $s^3$ and we want to find $x$ such that adding $x$ to each of the 6 faces of the cube of volume $s^3$ gives us a volume of $s^3 + V$ so the side lengths will now be $(s^3 + V)^{\frac{1}{3}} = s + 2x$.
So:
➡️$x = ((s^3 + V)^{\frac{1}{3}} - s)/2$
And finally for the outer layer with thickness y fixed, we want the final volume is $F = (s + 2x + 2y)^3$
Or:
➡️$F = ((s^3 + V)^{\frac{1}{3}} + 2y)^3$

I am a bit confused. If the length of a side of the innermost cube is a, the length of the (out)side of the middle cube is b, and the length of the (out)side of the outermost cube is c, the volume of the innermost cube is a^3, the volume of the middle 'shell' is b^3-a^3, and the volume of the outermost 'shell' is c^3-b^3...

That would make the thickness of the center shell (b-a)/2 and the thickness of the outermost shell (c-b)/2

@ness well yes, but in my scenario I’m not given a b or c which you have mentioned, I’m only given, a, b^3 - a^3, and (c-b)/2 as you state, so if those equations are correct I could most likely solve for b and c using those 3 givens.

if you know what b^3 - a^3 is and what a is, you know what b is.

so then if you know what (c-b)/2 is, you know what c is

Yeah, I figured that out from your first comments thank you
